# How is: $(n+1)!(n+1)+(n+1) = (n+2)!$?

Tags: number-theory, factorial

i want to show that $(n+1)!(n+1)+(n+1)! = (n+2)!$

i put it into wolfram and it showed this to be true, but im not sure why.

I need to show this as a part of a induction proof.

Comment: $ (n+1)!(n+1)+(n+1)!=(n+1)! (n+1  +  1)$ taking (n+1)! as your common factor.

Comment: Your title has a typo: the second term should be $(n+1)!$.  Incidentally, you've copied the error @user2277550 .

Answer (score 1):

Factor out $(n+1)!$ from both terms:

$$
(n+1)!\,(n+1)+(n+1)!=(n+1)!\left[(n+1)+1\right]=(n+1)!\,(n+2)=(n+2)!
$$

Comment: great, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Factor out the $(n+1)!$. Then use the fact that $(n+1)!(n+2)=\left(1(2)(3)..(n+1)\right)(n+2)=(n+2)!$.